# How to populate the Select tag in dynamically created HTML in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I think I'm stuck in a very different situation here.I have a dynamically created HTML which looks something like this:

```js
var values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];

var html = [
  '<div class="panel-container">',

  '<form class="form-inline bootstrap-form-with-validation">',
  '<div class="row">',
  '<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">',
  '<select id="' + name + '">',
  '<option>Select a Facility</option>',
  '</select>',
  '</div>',
  '<div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
  '<input class="input-input-row input-sign-in" placeholder="Enter Color" id="' + clr + '">',
  '</div>',
  '<div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
  '<button class="btn btn-default btn-input-row pull-right" type="button" id="' + colorise + '"><span class="span-input-row glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span></button>',
  '</div>',
  '</div>',
  '</form>',
  '</div>'
].join('\n');
$(_thisPanel.scrollContainer).append(html);
```

So now I need to add the values to the select tag on the div load, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: OK first of all @AlivetoDie I wanted some ideas not the right answer. I was searching for the ways in which I can solve this problem. Between I always vote for all those people who give me answers. I never un-mark them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demo uses:

- [**.insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [**.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [**ES6 Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Details are commented within the demo**

### Demo

```js
// Array of values for each <option> added to <select>
const colors = ['cyan', 'gold', 'tomato', 'lime'];

// Arbitrarily determined values
var selID = 'selA';
var colorIn = 'clrB';
var colorize = 'clrselC';

/* Using ES6 Template Literals to define dynamic HTML
|| Its a string with less limitations and more 
|| features than its lesser relative: String Literal.
|| Basics: Wrap in backticks: ` instead of quotes: " or '.
|| Replace this: "'+ val +'" with this: ${val}
*/
var markUp = `<div class="panel-container"><form class="form-inline bootstrap-form-with-validation"><div class="row"><div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><select id="${selID}"><option>Select a Facility</option></select></div><div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><input class="input-input-row input-sign-in" placeholder="Enter Color" id="${colorIn}"></div><div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><button class="btn btn-default btn-input-row pull-right" type="button" id="${colorize}"><span class="span-input-row glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div></div></form></div>`;

// Reference the <main> (main#dock)
const dock = document.querySelector('main');

/* Use .insertAdjacentHTML() to render the string (markUp) 
|| into HTML
*/
dock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markUp);

// Use .map() to...
colors.map(function(val, idx) {

  // Reference the new <select>
  let sel = document.getElementById(selID);

  // Create an <option>
  let opt = document.createElement('option');

  /* Set its value to the value of the colors[] array
  || index value
  */
  opt.value = val;

  /* Set its text content to that value as well so it'll
  || be visible within the <select> once appended.
  */
  opt.textContent = val;

  // append the <option> to the <select>
  sel.appendChild(opt);
});
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<main class='container'></main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP: *"So now I need to add the values to the select tag"* If you don't see it in my answer, I don't know how else to show you. The OP appears to understand and deemed it the most helpful. Perhaps it's because I've added extra ways to do things along with detailed explanations..

Comment: And when i run your example nothing happening?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the array contained colors, facilities, or giraffes, The data is an array of strings and the result is the same; which is values of array end up as values in an `<option>` within the dynamically generated `<select>`

Comment: It's chrome(Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)) i  am using. Also leave it to OP now

Comment: Perhaps if you put more effort in explaining your answer, the OP may accept your answer instead. Compare my answer and yours.  I think my answer explains things far better than: *"After-"* *"DO"*

Comment: Also you are obviously far more knowledgeable than I am since you have 31k+ and I have merely half of that. I guarantee that if you copy and paste my answer on a blank text file and change its extension to `.html` you will see the code function properly with or without the external scripts and stylesheets.  I find it very hard to believe a user such as yourself cannot see my code is correct and functioning just by looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];

 var selectHTML = '';

 values.forEach(value,()={

   selectHTML+= `<option${value}</option`

 });

 var html = [

 ...

 `<select`

 ${selectHTML`

 `</select`

 ...

 ];
```